# Cannot access Youtrack issue's custom field from workflow

Tags: youtrack

When I run custom workflow in YouTrack InCloud 2017.2:

```
rule Test for access to issue field 

when issue.becomesReported() { 
  Assignee = loggedInUser; 
}
```

I got:

> Cannot set value to custom field Assignee

and ticket is not created. Could anybody point me to a reason for that?
`Assignee` field has type `user` and it is actually default field.

Comment: The loggedInUser must also be included into the set of values of the Assignee field.

Comment: Thank you! it works fine. I will put your comment to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LiubovDievskaia kindly noticed the `loggedInUser` must be a member of a group that has access to the project. The same is correct of every user that is used as rhs value in any workflow rule